# Why do we repeat yhei shmei rabah?

Tags: tefilla

Why does the tzibur repeat y'hei shomei rabah after the Chazan? From a friend. Not why we say it but why does the tzibur repeat it.

Comment: Never seen anyone repeat anything. Have you?

Comment: I'm aware of two practices. (1) the leader and the congregation say "Yehei shmei..." in unison; and (2) the leader waits for the congregation to say it and then repeats it after them. There are, for example, ArtScroll siddurim of each stripe. But I have not seen what this question describes, the tzibur (= the congregation) repeating after the chazan (= the leader).

Answer (score 4):

It's not a repetition, it's the designated response of the congregation and an original part of the liturgy. In many communities the custom is for the chazzan to repeat it after the congregation, but this is not essential. The Bavli (Brachos 3a, Brachos 57a, Shabbas 119b) stresses the importance of responding (apparently to kaddish) in this way. Mahzor Vitry quotes R' Nahshon Rav Mesivta that ואמן שעונין יהא שמיה רבא מברך שעונין ביחד כנגד [גדלו] לי"י אתי ונרוממה שמו יחדיו.

The phrase is essentially an Aramaic translation of Ps. 113:2, which is a response to 113:1